# How can I force and error on an undefined hash key?

Tags: perl, hashmap, accessor

I'm trying to use the code from [make perl shout when trying to access undefined hash key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3381159), but it doesn't work.

I assume something has changed in the way `tie` works in the past 10 years.

The error I get is:

```
Safe::Hash must define either a TIEHASH() or a new() method at /home/bennett/work/stock/Indicator.pm line 97.
```

I only need this for about 5% of the hashes I use, and I'm hoping to use something that doesn't change the interface (i.e. `$foo{bar}`). That is, I'd prefer not to use `Moose` or something involving accessor methods.

Here's why: I want to turn it on for debugging and development, and turn it off, otherwise. The program and computer are slow enough as it is.

Any fixed up code (see the link above), or other solutions are welcome.

This is Perl 5, version 16, Subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-Linux-thread-multi

Comment: No, "nothing" has changed in the way `tie` works. The code in the linked answer still works. The error is in your modifications. Did you forget to load Tie::Hash early enough?

Comment: Dang.  Without thinking, I changed the `require;push @ISA` to `use parent`.  Apparently they aren't as "the same" as I thought.  Thanks.

Comment: That will make Tie::Hash the parent, not Tie::StdHash

Comment: Doh!  Well, that's just sloppy reading on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a *nonexistent* hash key, which is different from a hash key that exists but has an undefined value, you can use lock_hash from [Hash::Util](https://perldoc.pl/Hash::Util#Restricted-hashes). Note that it also restricts any values from changing. Unfortunately lock_keys, which otherwise is closer to what you ask for, does not cause an error on accessing a nonexistent key unless you try to set it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Hash::Util 'lock_hash';
my %foo = (a => 1, b => 2);
lock_hash %foo;
print $foo{c}; # error
```

This is the same underlying mechanism used by [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Const::Fast) for read-only hashes, but it is a bit confusing as it tries to act both as read-only (existing values can't be changed) and restricted (nonexistent keys can't be accessed).

Comment: This is much faster than using `tie` (since it doesn't involve calling a Perl sub, something rather slow, for each access of the hash).

Comment: [Variable::Magic](https://metacpan.org/pod/Variable::Magic) would also probably be much faster than tie, even though it would still involve sub call overhead.

Comment: Thanks!  The Hash::Util does just what I need.  I must investigate Variable::Magic, 'cause, well, it's magic.

Comment: Just to be clear... Hash::Util does error out if you try to read a key that isn't supposed to be there.  Since I'm using this for typo protection, that's perfect.  If it's a "valid" key that doesn't `exists`, I'll deal with that in the program.

Comment: lock_hash does, but lock_keys (which still allows existing values to be changed) does not.